# How to use components in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm working on a legacy MySql database and have the following entities:

```
public class Company
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDepartment
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that a company only use the department class if it has more than one department.

Right now I'm trying to make a company/department search, this means I need a list of all departments and therefore I need to "create" departments of all the companies that only has one department, and therefore don't have a entry in CompaynyDepartment.

To do this I was thinking of use components in fluent NHibernate, but I'm not sure I can join the real departments with the fake ones?

Is there a better approach to this problem? It's not an option to change the database structure.

Comment: Companies with only one department still have n departments right? Why not just represent this as a collection with one entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the database structure